# How do I get output file name containing page X of Y

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostscript to convert multipage pdf to png. I need to have the output filename of the png file as pageXofY.png where X is the page number and Y is the total number of pages in the pdf.

I know I can use page%d.png to get the current page number.

Can anyone help please? I have number of multipage pdf so manually renaming the png files is not an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in standard Ghostscript. The primary reason is that the device has no way to know the number of pages in the input. While this can be determined for a single input PDF file, if you had 2 input files, how would you know (while processing file 1) what the total number of pages in all the files was ?

You might be able to use the PDF interpreter to reset the OutputFile for the device, once the number of pages has been determined.

In /ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps look for the procedure /runpdfpagerange, the routine terminates:

```
       QUIET not { 
         (Processing pages ) print 1 index =only ( through ) print dup =only
         (.) = flush
       } if
     } ifelse
   } ifelse
} bind def
```

Immediately in front of the "}bind def" you could try adding something like:

```
10 LastPage cvs              %% (LastPage)
dup length 15 add string     %% (LastPage) string
dup (Page %d of ) exch copy  %% (LastPage) (Page %d of ) (Page %d of)
dup 12 3 index               %% (LastPage) (Page %d of ) (Page %d of) 12 (LastPage)
putinterval                  %% (LastPage) (Page %d of LastPage)
dup 3 1 roll                 %% (Page %d of LastPage) (Page %d of LastPage) (LastPage)
length 12 add                %% (Page %d of LastPage) (Page %d of LastPage) n
(.png) putinterval           %% (Page %d of LastPage.png)
<< /OutputFile 3 1 roll>> setpagedevice
```

Which *might* work, I haven't tried it.

Alternatively, use Ghostscript's pdf_info.ps to determine the number of pages in the input PDF file, then invoke Ghostscript a second time creating the OutputFile from the information returned by pdf_info.ps (eg -sOutputFile="Page %d of 100.png")

**update**

pdf_info.ps is distributed as part of the Ghostscript source, its not in the prepackaged Windows installer so you would need to pick up a copy of the source distribution (www.ghostscript.com, just download the sources rather than the Windows installer).

The file can be found in ghostpdl/gs/toolbin, if you open it with a text editor you'll see the usage near the top in a comment. Here's an example of the output:

```
D:\tests>\ghostpdl\gs\debugbin\gswin32c -dNODISPLAY -sFile=01_001.pdf /ghostpdl/
gs/toolbin/pdf_info.ps
GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.16 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.

        01_001.pdf has 9 pages

Title: 571l_p
Author: mwang
Subject: 571l_p
Keywords:
Creator: Adobe PageMaker 6.52
Producer: Acrobat Distiller 4.05 for Windows
CreationDate: D:20001113140954
ModDate: D:20010305115330-08'00'

Page 1 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 2 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 3 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 4 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 5 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 6 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 7 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 8 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0
Page 9 MediaBox: [0 0 612 792] CropBox: [0 0 612 792]    Rotate = 0

Fonts Needed that are not embedded (system fonts required):
    Arial
    Arial,Bold

D:\tests>
```

So you would need to output that to a file and scan it, or pipe the output through grep or something similar to find the number of pages.

Comment: Thank you for your input..I must admit that i am a novice as far ghostscript is concerned and am not aware of pdfInterpreter. Can you please elaborate on the ghostscript's pdf_info.ps solution? Is it possible to pass the number of pages using pdf_info.ps into a variable which can then passed to the -sOutputFile? If so any pointers to how to achieve this? I must add here that is using ghostscript on Windows 7 (not sure if that information helps in anyway).

Comment: Edited my answer as its too complex for a comment.